# Equal height columns by 960.gs framework

Tags: css, frameworks

Is there any css/layout way we can have equal height columns via 960.gs

right now i have been using **[jquery equal height script](http://www.cssnewbie.com/equalheights-jquery-plugin/)**

Any other recommended solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the [`inline-block`](http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/) css display type.  Depending upon your design that might do the trick, but won't if you need equal borders or backgrounds.

And you could use a `<table>`.  I know how politically incorrect that is, but tables do work and are not hack.   You may need to adjust the `<td>` style type for cellspacing and padding to get it compatible with the `gs.960`

Comment: let see i feel overall i have to pull up my socks.